# Automatically generate RSS feeds

Tags: php, rss, feed

I have information stored in a database that I want to use to create RSS feeds.

### What is the best way to do this?

Also, are there any PHP library/functions that I can pass the data to and they will take care of ensuring that any characters that need to be encoded/stripped are dealt with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP Universal Feed Generator](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4427-PHP-Generate-feeds-in-RSS-1-0-2-0-an-Atom-formats.html) is the one you are looking for.

It supports RSS 1.0, RSS 2.0 and ATOM

Comment: Am going to check this out now.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to dynamically create an XML, it's pretty much the same, you just need to look on way to format an RSS, and off you go.

After you created the rss - you can validate it here:
http://validator.w3.org/feed/

Here is a short wiki article on how it's supposed to be formatted: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rss

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the [Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.introduction.html) component, which is part of Zend Framework. Just have a look at [Zend_Feed_Writer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.writer.html) in the Reference Guide, to see how to export data as a feed.

Answer (score 1):

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed

Just look at this RSS-example (right click for Source Code). It's a functional and used RSS and all you really need is to create a HTML-similiar page with dynamic data yourself.

**EDIT:**

I personally don't see the point of using a plugin for this. It's so similiar to HTML that you may aswell just create it with given tags in above example.

Comment: I can create an RSS feed myself, no problem. But the feed is being generated from data stored in a database, which has some characters that break the feed. I was hoping a php library would take care of ensuring proper encoding of necessary characters, or stripping any that cannot be encoded.

Comment: htmlentities() should do the trick: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php